# Associate string[] to IEnumerable<T> and string to T in C# overloaded method

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I created 2 static overloaded methods for writing to a file using `System.IO.StreamWriter`. The first method should write a single line. And the second method should write many lines. I tried to make it generic so it can be used on more than just strings (i.e., other primitive types like `int`, `float`, `bool` or any object with `ToString()`).

```
public static void WriteLine<T>(string path, T t, bool append = false)
{
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(path, append))
    {
        file.WriteLine(t.ToString());
    }
}

public static void WriteLine<T>(string path, IEnumerable<T> ts, bool append = false)
{
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(path, append))
    {
        foreach (var t in ts)
        {
            file.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

However, my methods seem problematic. For instance, suppose I have the following code:

```
string pathString = @"C:\temp";
const string fileName = @"test.txt";
string path = Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);

const bool append = true;

string line = "single";
WriteLine(path, line, append);

string[] lines = { "first", "second", "third" };
WriteLine(path, lines, append);
```

Both calls to `WriteLine` resolve to the first of my 2 methods. I was hoping the first call to `WriteLine` would resolve to the 1st method since I'm passing a string and the second call to `WriteLine` would resolve to the 2nd method since I'm passing an array of strings. However, this is not the case.

Also, if I remove the first method `public static void WriteLine<T>(string path, T t, bool append = false)` then both calls to `WriteLine` resolve to `public static void WriteLine<T>(string path, IEnumerable<T> ts, bool append = false)` and I get the following output:

```
s
i
n
g
l
e
first
second
third
```

Furthermore, if I remove the second method `public static void WriteLine<T>(string path, IEnumerable<T> ts, bool append = false)` then both calls to `WriteLine` resolve to `public static void WriteLine<T>(string path, T t, bool append = false)` and I get the following output:

```
single
System.String[]
```

How can I correct my static overloaded `WriteLine` methods so that passing `string[]` as a parameter calls the `WriteLine` method with `IEnumerable<T>` and passing `string` as a parameter calls the `WriteLine` method with `T`?

At this point, I'm not sure if its possible. If its not, then I suppose I'll just have to rename the methods to `WriteLine(T t)` and `WriteLines(IEnumerable<T> ts)`

Comment: `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`. For this special case you might need an overload of `WriteLine(string s)`, or you can manually qualify the call as `WriteLine<string>(line)`.

Comment: The most readable approach is to not have an overload at all. Arguably, this is the best approach, because `WriteLine<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` does not write one line, it writes any number of lines, so it should be called `WriteLines<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` instead.

Comment: @codran - the reason I don't want an overload of `WriteLine(string s)` is so that I can pass in other primitive datatypes like `int` or `float` without explicitly having to cast it as a string. For example, `WriteLine(123)` or `WriteLine(1.23)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - at this point, I feel like renaming `WriteLine<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` to `WriteLines<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` is my only option. I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: So after generic type arguments are determined, you've got one overload taking `string[]`, and another overload taking `IEnumerable<string>`. Then the first is a better match. It's clear enough that that's not what you want, but you'd need a generic type constraint that C# doesn't have to get the first rejected. There might be some slightly different API that does allow you to use overloads here, but FWIW, I'd have gone with separate method names myself, like you and @dasblinkenlight suggested.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I feel much better about changing the method names so its not overloaded. It will now be `WriteLine()` and `WriteAllLines()`

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the type `T` anywhere in your method. You're calling `t.ToString()`, but `ToString()` is defined on `object`, so you don't need `T` to be known for that.

Therefore, what you could do is create non-generic methods, taking `object` and `IEnumerable`. At that point, you'd also need a third overload taking `string`, if you don't want that to print the individual characters, but you can implement the first in terms of the last.

```
public static void WriteLine(string path, object o, bool append = false)
{
    WriteLine(path, o.ToString(), append);
}

public static void WriteLine(string path, string s, bool append = false)
{
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(path, append))
    {
        file.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

public static void WriteLine(string path, IEnumerable e, bool append = false)
{
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(path, append))
    {
        foreach (var o in e)
        {
            file.WriteLine(o.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as mentioned in the comments, I'm not a fan of this API and I recommend you go with the renames (`WriteLine` vs. `WriteLines`) to highlight the functional difference between the two methods, but this same approach might be worthwhile for other methods, so should still be available as an answer.